# Kendo MVC ToDataSourceResult very slow with IQueryable EF function

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

For some reason when I use kendo extension ToDataSourceResult, my EF imported function runs many times slower than directly in the SQL Server.

My API:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get([ModelBinder(typeof(Kendo.Mvc.UI.WebAPI.DataSourceRequestModelBinder))] DataSourceRequest dataSourceRequest)
{
    DataSourceResult result = orderAccess.Get(UserID).ToDataSourceResult(dataSourceRequest);
}
```

My Get function:

```
public IQueryable Get(Guid userID)
{
    return db.fnOrdersGet(userID).AsQueryable();
}
```

fnOrdersGet was imported into EF:

```
[DbFunction("EntityModel", "fnOrdersGet")]
public virtual IQueryable<fnOrdersResult> fnOrdersGet(Nullable<System.Guid> userID) 
{
    var userIDParameter = userID.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("UserID", userID) :
            new ObjectParameter("UserID", typeof(System.Guid));
    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CreateQuery<fnOrdersResult>("[EntityModel].[fnOrdersGet](@UserID)", userIDParameter);
}
```

Using Glimpse, the query generated for count was (it takes 10s to run):

```
SELECT 
[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
    FROM [dbo].[fnOrdersGet](@UserID) AS [Extent1]
)  AS [GroupBy1]
```

And the paginated query was (it also takes 10s to run):

```
SELECT 
[Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Project1].[OrderID] AS [OrderID] 
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Extent1].[OrderID] AS [OrderID], 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM [dbo].[fnOrdersGet](@UserID) AS [Extent1]
)  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[OrderID] DESC
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
```

If I copy the queries shown above into SQL Server, they both run in a few milliseconds.

What could be done to improve this?

Comment: i am not sure but maybe `orderAccess.Get(UserID).ToList().ToDataSourceResult(dataSourceRequest)` helps

Comment: Thanks Gene R. I was very surprised that it ran in 14 seconds using orderAccess.Get(UserID).Cast<OrderResult>().ToList().ToDataSourceResult(dataSourceRequest‌​). But this is actually returning ALL the records and then doing the filtering and pagination. I really don't want that, because the number of records can grow quite fast.

Comment: what is db.fnOrdersGet()? and it should return generic list

Comment: It's a function imported in EF. I've updated my question with that info.